# Get ParentNode and ChildNodes from XML with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need the following data

[image]

I need to get them all in a single query, I have the following code:

```cs
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.LoadXml(prueba);

                XmlNode itemNodes = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//response//result//doc");
                var itemNodes2 = new List<XmlNode>(itemNodes.Cast<XmlNode>());
                var obtener = itemNodes.ParentNode.Attributes["numFound"].Name;
                var obtener2 = itemNodes.ParentNode.Attributes["numFound"].Value;
                var nodes = (from XmlNode node in itemNodes2
                             select new
                             {
                                 node.Attributes["name"].Value,
                                 node.InnerText

                                 
                             })
                             .Union
                             (from XmlNode node2 in itemNodes
                              select new
                              {
                                  node2.ParentNode.Attributes["numFound"].Name,
                                  node2.ParentNode.Attributes["numFound"].Value
                              }
                              )
                             .ToList();
```

In the first "select" I get all the child nodes of "doc".
Now I just need to get the `numFound`
The problem is that in the second "select" I have the following error:

> "Does not contain a definition for Union"

obtener = "numFound"
obtener2" = "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try naming the values in the first part of your union, in the second part the names are implied by the variables they come from;

```
        var nodes = (from XmlNode node in itemNodes2
                     select new
                     {
                         Name = node.Attributes["name"].Value,
                         Value = node.InnerText
                     })
                    .Union
                    (from XmlNode node2 in itemNodes
                    select new
                    {
                        node2.ParentNode.Attributes["numFound"].Name,
                        node2.ParentNode.Attributes["numFound"].Value
                    }
                    )
                    .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Try getting each part first and making sure they are valid, i.e.

```
        var part1 = from XmlNode node in itemNodes2
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = node.Attributes["name"].Value,
                        Value = node.InnerText
                    };
        var part2 = from XmlNode node2 in itemNodes
                    select new
                    {
                        node2.ParentNode.Attributes["numFound"].Name,
                        node2.ParentNode.Attributes["numFound"].Value
                    };

        var nodes = part1.Union(part2).ToList();
```

Comment: I did what you told me and:
'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Xml.XmlAttributeCollection.this[string].get devolvió null.

:(

Comment: ok, my part 2 get null, soo, my query has an error mmmmmm

Comment: thanks my error  is my query 2, thanks !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!